# 400 Bad Request SEC-43

Tags: php, curl, bad-request

Have a function (code below) for verifying that a URL actually exists, and ran into one that fails. It [works fine](https://www.bergenadventistkirke.com) in the browser though, which is why I'm very curious as to *why* this URL fails the way it does.

The response I get back is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
content-length: 378
x-synthetic: true
expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
connection: close
date: Sat, 25 Mar 2017 14:05:45 UTC
x-contextid: 1INsx8lY/G2fZ1ojZ
x-via: 1.1 echo105

<html>
<head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<style> body { background-color: #F2F2F2; color: #3E3E3E; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; } pre { word-wrap: break-word; } </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
<p><pre>1INsx8lY/G2fZ1ojZ @ Sat, 25 Mar 2017 14:05:45 GMT</pre>
<p><pre>SEC-43</pre>
<p><pre></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

The cryptic context id and timestamp keeps changing, but otherwise I get the same thing.

- Seems to happen no matter what page I try with on that website
- Happens both locally (xampp on windows), and remotely on a web hotel I have access (one.com, unix/lamp-type-stack)
- Tried setting the user-agent to a copy of my firefox one, but no help there either.
- Running `curl -i -X HEAD https://www.bergenadventistkirke.com` in a terminal *does* work however... but that just makes me more confused...

I've tried to search for "bad request" and "SEC-43", but all I seem to get up is a bunch of results that show that same error html. Clicking on them leads to bad certificates, other errors, or they redirect to somewhere else.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Malware? Some sort of magic non-browsers traffic blocking?

---

**The code**

```
<?php
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bergenadventistkirke.com',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
]);
ob_start();
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c); 

header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're checking for a `User-Agent` header and returning back a `HTTP 400 Bad Request` if they don't see one. `curl` at the command line sets a user agent of `curl/7.46.0`, which is why it works.

Try:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.bergenadventistkirke.com',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "curl/7.46.0"
]);
ob_start();
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Hm, that's weird... I tried to set the user-agent before, and I got the same error then, but now it works  Oh well, that did answer the question, and I can sleep again, thanks!